# Adding nodes to a BST tree and getting occurrence if node exists

Tags: java, data-structures, addition, binary-search-tree

I am running into a problem with my add method for my tree. I am trying to add nodes too a BST. The issue is the add method is adding a node when that data already exists in the tree. I comparing the nodes to be adding by the string data. The data is being added in A-Z fashion and when I traverse the tree that is what I get to print. But I do not want duplicates, if a String already exists in the tree it should increment the occurrence of that string.

```
public boolean add(String data)
{
    if(data.compareTo(this.data) == 0){
        occurance++;
        return false;
    }
    if(data.compareTo(this.data) < 0 ){
        if(leftNode == null ){
            leftNode  = new NSString(data, null, null, 0);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return leftNode.add(data);
    }

    if(data.compareTo(this.data) > 0){
        if(rightNode == null){
            rightNode = new NSString(data, null, null, 0);
            return true;
        }else
            return rightNode.add(data);
    }

    return false;

}// end method add()
```

That is the method inside the node class which is called by an add method in the tree class which looks like.

```
public boolean add(String data)
{
    if(root == null){
        root = new NSString(data,null,null, 1);
        return true;
    }else
        return root.add(data);

}// end method add()
```

Comment: Does a `NSString` contain references to its left and right children?

Comment: Yes,NSString it the class that contains references and the get/set methods. The top add method is in the NSString class and the bottom is in the tree class

Comment: Another quick question: what are the arguments for the `NSString` constructor?

Comment: The code looks fine. Can you provide some examples of the "duplicates"?

Comment: The constructor looks like:   public NSString( String d, NSString l, NSString r, int occ)                                                      the Console window prints something similar to this.                  a, LN: 37, Occurance: 1
a, LN: 60, Occurance: 1
a, LN: 71, Occurance: 1
a, LN: 77, Occurance: 1

Comment: Is it possible the compareTo() method is the problem? I was playing a little with the debugger and I don't believe the strings are ever evaluated equal. Which in turn would mean nothing ever gets incremented.

Comment: The code works fine for me. It increments when duplicates are encountered. None of the examples you mentioned above include duplicates. By the way is there any particular reason why the add() in the node initializes the occurance to 0 where as the one in the tree initializes to 1?

Comment: 0 I had at first and just never changed. I thought about it more and changed to 1 because the first time enters the tree that is an occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste the input strings you are passing in. I am especially interested to see if your strings have whitespaces and therefore even if your output statements seem to have duplicates , they are not the same.

Also, can you please post the function which you are using to traverse the tree

PS:-
I think you should change the code for the below 2 lines . Change the occurence from 0 t 1
leftNode  = new NSString(data, null, null, 0);
 rightNode = new NSString(data, null, null, 0);
If you want occurence with a zero based index, then change this 
root = new NSString(data,null,null, 1);

Answer (score 0):

problem in compareTo () api. the input data processing might be giving the result as not equal to zero.